# Are there any recent resources on this variation of the Two Knights Caro-Kann?

Tags: caro-kann

The variation I'm talking about is this:

1. e4 c6
2. Nc3 d5
3. Nf3 a6!?.

I'm interested in knowing some plans and ideas connected to the 3. ... a6!? move. I saw it originally in this game: https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=4237916.

Comment: I don't play the Caro-Kann, but from clicking around a bit, the idea seems to be to avoid 3...Bg4 4.h3 Bh5 5.exd5 cxd5 6.Bb5+
I don't know if there's much more to it.